# webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown runs several time when I press a key

Tags: c#

```
private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
          if (click_counter > 0)
              {
                  click_counter = 0;
                  return;
                }                
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
                {

                    searchButton.PerformClick();
                }
        }
```

I added this code into my form source code which has a webbrowser object. 
The problem is messagebox pops up 3 times when I click letter "S".

How can I get rid of that problem?

Thanks
EDITED: Removed MessageBox.Show per recommendation!

SOLVED: I solved it out with a workaround. I cannot call it a real solution though. what I did is adding a if condition in the beginning to control the click count. Any better solution is welcome!

Comment: Have you tried using KeyDown as support, too? By looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx) I found this: `PreviewKeyDown is where you preview the key. Do not put any logic here, instead use the KeyDown event after setting IsInputKey to true.`

Comment: I have not tried that. Can you please write a sample code?

Answer (score 3):

Do *not* use MessageBox in event handlers, it pumps a message loop which can greatly disturb the normal flow of events.  Especially the kind that are raised because of Windows notifications and delivered by the message loop dispatcher, like PreviewKeyDown.

Use Debug.Print() to display diagnostics in the Output window.  And of course don't forget about debugger breakpoints.

Comment: This does not answer my question but thanks for the advice. I am not gonna use it. It is just for test purposes. But the problem is when I click letter S it is called several times although it is pressed only 1 time.

Comment: @Val Nolav: It doesn't mater if it is in test or production scenarios, just don't use it!

Comment: It was not advice, it is an *answer* that explains why the event didn't work properly.  If you still have a problem after removing the MessageBox.Show() call then you need to document your next attempt better.

Comment: yes, I removed MessageBox.Show and instead I added searchButton.PerformClick(); the problem is search button is getting clicked several times